# Production time between episodes of Back in Time For Dinner?

Tags: production, back-in-time-for-dinner

We've been following the Australian version of Back in Time for Dinner on the ABC, and got to wondering how much real time elapses over the season.

Each decade/episode is obviously recorded over a week - each day features a specific year, and they skip some years. It also looks like they start on Sunday and run through to Saturday.

There must be enough time in between each recording week to reconstruct, refit and refurnish the kitchen (including piping gas), dining room, and living room. So, it's unlikely that the whole series was filmed in a single six week block.

Also, looking at the youngest daughter, she obviously ages somewhat over the series.

I haven't found much behind the scenes information through google.

So - how much real time takes place in between each episode?

In other words, is there a production schedule anywhere?

Comment: The ABC website indicates that each episode covers a specific decade - http://www.abc.net.au/tv/programs/back-in-time-for-dinner/ 1950s/60s/70s/80s/90s/00s/Future

Comment: @Paulie_D I know that... I've watched the show. I'm asking how much real time is there between episodes during recording.

Comment: Then you need to edit the question to clarify because it's not clear right now.